# What steps can I take to make a worfklow activity resilient to exceptions

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am very new to Workflow Foundation development, and am worried that I am opening serious holes in our business process handling by not properly handling application / database exceptions in custom activities.

I would appreciate some steps that I could take to add this resiliency to my custom activities so that I can easily use the designer and other tools to ensure that, as far as I can, I do not create custom activities that are brittle and likely to cause workflow cleanup issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as custom activities goes you should treat them as any other piece of code. Handle the errors you can and let you can't handle the rest bubble up.

At the workflow level you can use the TryCatch activity and workflow persistence to deal with errors. Specially persistence is something people overlook often. Add Persist activities at appropriate steps in your workflow and  set the workflow to abort on unhandled errors. Now you can go back in and reload the last good workflow state and retry the actions that cause an unhandled exception. A great way of recovering from failures with resources like databases that might be unavailable for some reason and then come back.

Comment: More than `Persist` people tend to overlook exceptions handling. Especially a client without programming knowledge tend to look at the designer and its easiness to drag and drop activities as a puzzle maker which *just works*. Some times the pieces fit but underlying exceptions may occur anyway. In such cases, and as I stated in my answer, I usually hide, from the designer, an activity that I known that may thrown exceptions, providing an `IActivityTemplateFactory` just to surround it with `TryCatch` instead.

Comment: Just adding a TryCatch doesn't buy you much if there is no strategy for handling the error in some way. There are times where you can just continue and ignore it but these are rare.

Comment: If you are using a workflow service, add the Persist activity at appropriate places, will the workflow automatically resume at the last persisted spot prior to the exception?

Comment: Or do you need to use the workflow control endpoint to do the resume?

Comment: Maurice - I'm looking at the web.config and setting the <workflowUnhandledException action=""/> to configure it to abort on unhandled exceptions, and the four allowed values are: Abandon, Cancel, Terminate and AbandonAndSuspend. Which should I use to "abort" as you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: With a workflow service Abort is named Abandon :-( use either Abandon or AbandonAndSuspend. The first will allow the WSH to resume the workflow when it want. It only does so with a Delay or external message though. With AbandonAndSuspend the workflow instance is suspended and will not resume untill you resume it. You can do so through a control endpoint or through the AppFabric UI/API.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Maurice. One last (I hope) question is: you mention either a delay or an external message. The delay I understand. Does the external message mean a receive/receiveandsendreply?

Comment: The external message can be a Receive but it is basically any bookmark that is being resumed as that reloads the workflow instance. The Receive also uses bookmarks internally.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some options, at different execution stages, that are available for you to use to handle exceptions.

---

**First option (at activity/workflow execution time):**

First of all, on custom activities, you should always try to treat exceptions inside it's execution. Some activities might not work but the overall workflow can continue and, in such cases, log the error to persistence and even show the user that *something didn't work as expected but the thing will continue* are good options.

That being said there'll always be cases where an activity have to (and even should) thrown exceptions and those should be treated at workflow level. Something like: *if this exception occurs on this activity, do this, otherwise, do that*.

Lets imagine you've a custom activity which persists something to DB:

```
public sealed PersistIntegerToDb : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<int> ValueToPersist { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        try
        {
            // persist
        }
        catch(SqlException exception) 
        {
            // re throws the SqlException

            throw new SqlException("'ValueToPersist' wasn't persisted.", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code or through designer you've available [TryCatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.trycatch.aspx) activity to catch that error and treat it the way you want:

```
var workflow = new TryCatch
{
    Try = new PersistIntegerToDb
    {
        ValueToPersist = 10
    },
    Catches =
    {
        new Catch<SqlException>
        {
            Action = new ActivityAction<SqlException>
            {
                Handler = new WriteLine 
                {
                     Text = "An error occurred and the value wasn't saved! Anyway workflow will continue..."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can terminate it using [TerminateWorkflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.terminateworkflow.aspx).

---

**Second option (at design time):**

Ok, but you can argue that *client doesn't know that he have to handle those cases*. In that case, and this is an usability option you might consider, instead of making available `PersistIntegerToDb` on the designer, you can provide an activity already surrounded by exceptions catches to handle, through [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx):

```
public sealed PersistIntegerToDbFactory : IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    public Activity Create(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return new TryCatch
        {
            Try = new PersistIntegerToDb
            {
                ValueToPersist = 10
            },
            Catches =
            {
                new Catch<SqlException>
                {
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now you just add `PersistIntegerToDbFactory`as if it were a regular activity:

```
new ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof(PersistIntegerToDbFactory), null, "Persist Integer");
```

---

**Third option (at validation time):**

Never forget to [validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd779572.aspx) workflow before execution!

```
var validationResults =
    ActivityValidationServices.Validate(workflow);

foreach(var error in validationResults.Errors)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
        "Validation error '{0}', generated on activity '{1}' in the property named {2}",
        error.Message,
        error.Source.DisplayName,
        error.PropertyName));
}
```

---

**Fourth option (at application execution time):**

You can handle all not treated exception that might happen during execution, using OnUnhandledException event:

```
var wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(activity);

wfApp.OnUnhandledException += 
    delegate(WorkflowApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.UnhandledException is SqlException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some data wasn't properly persited.");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown error: " + e.UnhandledException.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("With message: " + e.UnhandledException.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ok, workflow will be abort");

        return UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
    };
```

Note that, at this stage, you can only [Abort, Cancel and Terminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.unhandledexceptionaction.aspx) the workflow and that's the reason why you should 1) avoid throwing exceptions or 2) treat exceptions inside your workflow. `OnUnhandledException` is your last chance to end the workflow execution gracefully and should always be treated even if for logging purposes. Something like [DivideByZeroExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception.aspx) can occur and are almost impossible to predict and catch at validation time, for example.